# Button Command Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a button inside a listbox.
I want to bind the command to the DataContext of the Main Grid.
I'm not sure who to do this, below is my attempt.

I want to bind to ViewModel.SelectionEditorSelectionSelectedCommand on my view model, which the main grid is bound to, I don't want to bind to the actual filteredSelection.SelectionEditorSelectionSelectedCommand

Here is my XAML

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid">
   .....
    <ListBox x:Name="MarketsListBox"  Height="Auto" MaxHeight="80" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FilteredMarkets}" Margin="5" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                 >
          ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button Height="Auto" 
                                    Content="{Binding FinishingPosition,Converter={StaticResource FinishingPositionToShortStringConverter1}}" 
                                    Foreground="{Binding Path=FinishingPosition, Converter={StaticResource FinishingPositionToColourConverter1}}" 
                                    Margin="2" Width="20"
                                    Command="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid.DataContext, Path=SelectionEditorSelectionSelectedCommand}" 
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                    />
    .....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding to the grid using `ElementName` should work, but you have made a small error in the binding syntax. `ElementName` must include the name *only*, not a property. You simply need to include `DataContext` in the `Path`:

```
Command="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid,
                  Path=DataContext.SelectionEditorSelectionSelectedCommand}"
```

Comment: I'll give that a go see how I get on

Answer (score 1):

So based on this line:

```
Command="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid.DataContext ... }
```

I'm assuming you have something like this:

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <lol:GridViewModel /> <!--Some kind of view model of sorts-->
    </Grid.DataContext>
    ... content
</Grid>
```

Then all you would have to do is on the ViewModel class create a public property that returns some sort of `ICommand`, such as:

```
class GridViewModel {
    public ICommand SelectionEditorSelectionSelectedCommand { 
        get { return new TestCommand(); } 
    }
}
```

Where `TestCommand` would be some kind of class implementing `ICommand` as in:

```
class TestCommand : ICommand {
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged { get; set; }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true; // Expresses whether the command is operable or disabled.
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
         // The code to execute here when the command fires.
    }
}
```

Basically, for `ICommand` you just need to define what happens when the command `Executes`, how to determine whether or not it `CanExecute` and then supply an event handle for when `CanExecuteChanged`. Once you have this setup, all you have to do is wire up your button like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding SelectionEditorSelectionSelectedCommand}" />
```

And that's it. Basically the binding will automatically check your ViewModel class for a property called `SelectionEditorSelectionSelectedCommand`, that implements `ICommand`. When it reads the property it will instantiate an instance of `TestCommand`, and WPF will handle it from there. When the button is clicked `Execute` will be fired like clockwork.

Answer (score 0):

You should try as I did in a similar situation:

```
<Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=DataContext.YOURCOMMANDHERE}" />
```

I had a button inside a TabItem Header and it worked Ok!
The thing is, your Command is a Property of the DataContext, so your path should indicate it.

Good Luck!

EDIT: Elementname might work as well.